# Facebook messenger secret conversation with a bot

Tags: facebook, bots

Facebook offers a way to handle secret conversations between two physical devices/users. Look at [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1084673321594605/?helpref=hc_fnav)
I'm looking for a way to create secret conversations between users and a bot deployed on Facebook Messenger platform. Is it possible?

Is it mandatory create a Facebook Page to deploy a bot on Facebook Messenger platform? If so, can i hide the messages exchanged between users and the bot on Facebook Page?

Comment: The Messenger Bot platform _is_ for communication between a user and a page - so what your bot even _do_, if you did _not_ create a page to “deploy” it to? And no, secret conversations are not available for bots.

Comment: I just needed a confirmation. Thank you